# Си, матрицы и подпрограммы (не могу найти ошибку)

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы, исследование

Задача: Даны три вещественные квадратные матрицы n порядка. Напечатать ту из них, норма которой наименьшая (считать, что такая матрица одна). В качестве нормы матрицы взять максимум абсолютных величин её элементов.

Написал программу, но работает она не так как нужно. 
(Возможно где то совсем глупо ошибся, времени 4 часа, засыпаю :D)
Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку, утром нужно сдать.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define n 50
void input_matr(int[n][n], int k, char);
void print_matr(int[n][n], int k, char);
int norma(int[n][n], int k);
void input_matr(int x[n][n], int k, char Name)
//ввод матриц
{
int i, j;
printf(" Введите матрицу : %c\n", Name);
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d]= ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%f", &x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
void print_matr(int x[n][n], int k, char Name)
//печать матрицы
{
int i, j;
printf("Матрица %c\n", Name);
for (i = 0; i<k; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<k; j++)
        printf("%d\t", x[i][j]);
    printf("/n");
}
}
int norma(int x[n][n], int k)
//вычисление нормы через abs
{
int i, j, max;
max = abs(x[0][0]);
for (i = 0; i<k; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<k; j++)
    {
        if (max<abs(x[i][j]))
            max = abs(x[i][j]);
    }
}
return max;
}
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
int A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n];
int k;
printf(" Введите k: "); 
scanf("%d", &k);
input_matr(A, k, 'A');
input_matr(B, k, 'B');
input_matr(C, k, 'C');
if (norma(A, k)<norma(B, k) && norma(A, k)<norma(C, k))
    print_matr(A, k, 'A');
else if (norma(B, n)<norma(A, n) && norma(B, n)<norma(C, n))
    print_matr(B, n, 'B');
else
    print_matr(C, n, 'C');
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в задании написано

> Даны три **вещественные** квадратные матрицы

Однако вы объявляете матрицы как целочисленные

```
int A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n];
^^^
```

Тем не менее пытаетесь ввести элементы матрицы как числа с плавающей запятой

```
scanf("%f", &x[i][j]);
      ^^^
```

В функции `print_matr` вы используете не ту наклонную черточку

```
printf("/n");
       ^^^
```

Должно быть

```
printf("\n");
       ^^^
```

При выводе матрицы в этих предложениях

```
else if (norma(B, n)<norma(A, n) && norma(B, n)<norma(C, n))
    print_matr(B, n, 'B');
                 ^^^ 
else
    print_matr(C, n, 'C');
                 ^^^
```

вы вместо переменной `k` используете переменную `n`.

Программа в общих чертах может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define n 5

void input_matr( double[n][n], size_t, char );
void print_matr( double[n][n], size_t, char );
double norma( double[n][n], size_t );

void input_matr( double m[n][n], size_t k, char name )
{
    size_t i, j;
    printf( "Введите матрицу : %c\n", name );
    for ( i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
        {
            printf("[%d][%d]= ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%lf", &m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_matr( double m[n][n], size_t k, char Name)
{
    size_t i, j;
    printf( "Матрица %c\n", Name );
    for ( i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ ) printf( "%lf\t", m[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

double norma( double m[n][n], size_t k )
{
    size_t i, j;
    double max = fabs( m[0][0] );

    for ( i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
        {
            if ( max < fabs( m[i][j] ) ) max = fabs( m[i][j] );
        }
    }

    return max;
}


int main( void )
{
    double A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n];
    size_t k;

    printf( "Введите k: " );
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &k ) != 1 || n < k ) k = n;

    input_matr( A, k, 'A' );
    input_matr( B, k, 'B' );
    input_matr( C, k, 'C' );

    double a_norma = norma(A, k);
    double b_norma = norma(B, k);
    double c_norma = norma(C, k);

    if (!(b_norma < a_norma) && !(c_norma < a_norma))
    {
        print_matr(A, k, 'A');
    }
    else if (!(c_norma < b_norma))
    {
        print_matr(B, k, 'B');
    }
    else
    {
        print_matr(C, k, 'C');
    }
}
```

Нужные вам заголовки, как, например, заголовок для локалей, и соответствующий код добавьте сами.